# Why is iSCSI support not included on the alternate installer?

Tags: server, iscsi, debian-installer

Does anyone know the reason that Canonical decided not to include the ability to install to iSCSI using the "alternate" installation CD (on 10.04 at least)?

Ubuntu 10.04 Server installation CD support installing to iSCSI, but when you try to follow the same steps in the alternate installer the options needed are not there...  So far I have been installing "ubuntu-desktop" onto the server installation after-the-fact, but this is tedious.

Since both use the same installer, I can only assume it was a conscious decision not to include it...  **Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colin Watson answered this in [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+question/186208):

> I think it was just because I didn't expect much demand for it and it
>   would have been an extra half-megabyte on the already
>   strapped-for-space alternate install CD. You're more than welcome to
>   consider it a wishlist bug, though - questions aren't a very good way
>   to record this kind of suggestion for the longer term.